# Confusion around priority of tokens in lark grammar

Tags: lark-parser

Following up from an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70730966/recognizing-multi-line-sections-with-lark-grammar), I'm a bit confused about the precedence of the `/.+/` regex line; I would expect the below test to produce

```
  line
  line  x
  chunk abc
```

instead I get:

```
  line
  line  x
  line  abc
```

```
    def test_tokenizing(self):
        p = Lark(r"""

        _NL: /\n/
        line.-1: /.+/? _NL
        chunk: /abc/ _NL
        start: (line|chunk)+

        """, parser='lalr')

        text = '\nx\nabc\n'
        print(p.parse(text).pretty())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lark, priorities mean different things for rules and for terminals.

Just a quick reminder, rules have lowercase names, while terminals have UPPERCASE names.

In LALR mode, priorities on rules only affect which one is chosen in case of a reduce/reduce collision. It has no effect on the terminals inside it.

What you want is to change the priority on the terminal itself:

```
def test_tokenizing():
    p = Lark(r"""

    _NL: /\n/
    line: EVERYTHING? _NL
    EVERYTHING.-1: /.+/
    chunk: /abc/ _NL
    start: (line|chunk)+

    """, parser='lalr')

    text = '\nx\nabc\n'
    print(p.parse(text).pretty())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help on this one. I love lark so far